# Single Prediction when using Batch Normalization

Tags: deep-learning, classification, batch-normalization

I have a CNN that is learning pretty well on a dataset I created. I added Batch Normalization to this network to try to improve the performances.

But ..  when I try to make a prediction on a single image I always end up with the same result (whatever the image). I think it is because I need batches to actually do batch normalization.

So is it possible to do a prediction on a single image with a CNN using BN ?
I thought about deleting BN layers once my network is done training, is it the way to go ?

Thank you :)

Comment: This is not a problem caused by batch normalization, it is probably something else, so provide more details.

Comment: i really think it actually is caused by batch normalization because when i make prediction feeding my network with a batch of images (and not a single image) it works. But i would like to make a prediction feeding a single image.

Comment: Well I cannot reproduce such behavior with my models, they always worked well with BN and a single image batch. And also at test time the normalization statistics are fixed, not computed in a batch. All of this points to a problem in your code rather than the technique.

Comment: Yes normalization parameters (scale and offset) are learn during training and fixed for testing but don't you still need to compute mean andvariance through your batch ? (see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/moments)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the exact answer and the problem I face here : https://r2rt.com/implementing-batch-normalization-in-tensorflow.html
in the "Making predictions with the model" it is explained that when using BN, during training time you need to estimate the population mean and population variance on your training set so you don't have to use batch when doing testing (which would be "cheating") :)

Comment: And you encountered this only during single observation predictions? Had your predictions been a batch of images just like training this won't happen right?

Comment: Will https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict_on_batch help here?